# Storybook custom webpack loading empty scss objects

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, storybook

I added a custom **webpack.config.js** file to my `.storybook` project so that I can import `.scss` files. This is what I added, straight from the storybook docs.

```
const path = require('path');

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = (storybookBaseConfig, configType) => {
  // configType has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
  // You can change the configuration based on that.
  // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

  // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
  storybookBaseConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
  });

  // Return the altered config
  return storybookBaseConfig;
};
```

Here's my story:

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { linkTo } from '@storybook/addon-links'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import Button from './'
import ButtonStyles from './index.scss'
import ButtonCompareTrayStyles from './compare-tray.scss'
import ButtonCompareRemminderStyles from './compare-reminder.scss'

console.log({ButtonStyles, ButtonCompareTrayStyles, ButtonCompareRemminderStyles})

storiesOf('Button', module)
  .add('with text', () => <Button onClick={action('clicked')}>Hello Button</Button>)
  .add('with some emoji', () => <Button onClick={action('clicked')}>   </Button>)
  .add('with default styles', () => <Button styles={ButtonStyles} onClick={action('clicked')}>Hello World</Button>)
  .add('with CompareTray styles', () => <Button styles={ButtonCompareTrayStyles} onClick={action('clicked')}>Hello World</Button>)
  .add('with CompareRemminder styles', () => <Button styles={ButtonCompareRemminderStyles} onClick={action('clicked')}>Hello World</Button>)
```

When I log some Button styles, it appears that each one of these objects is empty.

[image]

Why are these objects empty? How can I get scss working with storybook?

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this eventually ? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you point to the right folders sass-loader? I suppose that it may somehow depend on where (which folder) you execute the script and thus wrong path to SCSS files could be used

Answer (score 2):

For everyone who has the same problems, I added the package `@storybook/preset-scss` and configured it the following way:

```js
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.*",
    "../src/**/*.story.*"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-actions",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs",
    {
      name: '@storybook/preset-scss',
      options: {
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          modules: true
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

That's it.